# Парсинг класа - js

Tags: javascript, парсер

есть вот такой кусочек скрипта, который получает h3 с классом "r"и выводит true/false, но теперь r есть всегда и я хочу сделать так - если один r - это false, если два r - это true. Подскажите, как добавить проверку на наличие одновременно 2-ух классов "r". Буду очень благодарен, хорошего кода всем.

```
   function isIndexed(page,ignoreCase) {
  var urls=[],RETRIES=5;

  if(!page)return;

  if(page.indexOf("://")!==-1)page=page.split("://")[1].trim();

  var url='https://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(page)+'&fp=1&dpr=2&sns=1&pf=p&tch=1&filter=0';

  if(page.slice(-1)=="/")page=page.slice(0,-1);

  try {
    var serp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{muteHttpExceptions:true,method:"GET",followRedirects:true});
    var result=serp.getContentText().split('/*""*/');

    var searchResults,serpResults,isIndexed=false;

    for(var i=2;i<result.length-1;i++) { 
      searchResults=JSON.parse(result[i]);
      serpResults=searchResults.d.split('<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=');
      isIndexed=findIndexedURL(serpResults, page, ignoreCase);
      if(isIndexed) return "Yes";
    }
    return "No";

  } catch(e) { return "No"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isIndexed(page,ignoreCase) {
  var urls=[],RETRIES=5;

  if(!page)return;

  if(page.indexOf("://")!==-1)page=page.split("://")[1].trim();

  var url='https://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(page)+'&fp=1&dpr=2&sns=1&pf=p&tch=1&filter=0';

  if(page.slice(-1)=="/")page=page.slice(0,-1);

  try {
    var serp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{muteHttpExceptions:true,method:"GET",followRedirects:true});
    var result=serp.getContentText().split('/*""*/');

    var searchResults,serpResults,isIndexed=false;
    var count // количество r

    for(var i=2;i<result.length-1;i++) { 
      searchResults=JSON.parse(result[i]);
      serpResults=searchResults.d.split('<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=');
      isIndexed=findIndexedURL(serpResults, page, ignoreCase);
      if(isIndexed) count++ // добавляет +1 к количеству r
    }
    
    // если r двое
    if (count === 2)
      return "Yes";
    
    return "No";

  } catch(e) { return "No"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так.

```js
var r1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].classList.contains('r');
var r2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[1].classList.contains('r');

console.log(r1 && r2);
```

```html
<h1 class="r">First</h1>
<h1 class="r">Second</h1>
```